# Simple C syntax Question

Tags: c, syntax

I ran into the following code in an old exam of the C course I'm taking:

```
struct QuestionSet{
    char q1:1;
    char q2:1;
    char q3:1;
}
```

I have no idea what the syntax "char q1:1" means, and I haven't been able to find it anywhere in "The C Programming Language" which is the course book. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Such a terrible book to use as a course book...

Comment: Duplicate. I can't blame you for not searching, though, because it is rather hard to search for given only that wonky syntax.

Comment: Though I should add that, for C, you can't use a `char` for a bitfield, and you ought to pay a lot of attention to whether your bitfields are signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [bitfield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field).  The number after the colon indicates the number of bits to assign to the struct element.  So the three elements are all one bit wide, and are able to store two values: 0, and either 1 or -1 (depending on your compiler, though -1 would be the more logical option when considering two's-complement arithmetic).

Comment: Okay, but I thought that a char by definition was 1 BYTE long. How does that work?

Comment: It's not clear that a `char:1` bit field can store the value 1.  First of all, the only valid types for a bit field are `int` (which in this context only can be signed or unsigned), `signed int`, `unsigned int`, and `_Bool`.  Anything else is a compiler-specific extension (but a fairly common one).  But if plain `char` is signed, it's possible (but not guaranteed) that `char q1:1` can only hold the values 0 and -1.  Plain `char` bit fields are non-portable.

Comment: A bit field has a size (in bits) specified by the constant following the `:`, regardless of the declared type.

Comment: i think here "char q1:1" here if we are using char then we can here maximum bytes 8 bits , i mean "char q1:15"  will give error...if we use int insted of char then this limits will be differ.  this is just shake of padding ...al though simply unsign q1:1 also works fine...

Comment: @Keith: I've updated my answer with regards to the numeric range of the fields.

Comment: @cdhowie: Great -- but don't forget that the ability to use `char` bit fields *at all* is a non-standard compiler extension.  There's really no reason not to use either `unsigned int q1:1;` or `signed int q1:1;` here.

Comment: @Keith: Sure, but the OP was asking what the code meant.  I believe I've explained that sufficiently.  The type issue is tangential to his question.

Comment: @cdhowie: The code means two things: (1) q1, q2, and a3 are bit fields; (2) they depend on a compiler extension, and may not be portable.  Both pieces of information are important.

Answer (score 1):

Bitfields are often used in microcontrollers programming, because it helps mapping registers in memory. For example, for a 8 bits register, if each bit has a different meaning/usage, it is possible to represent the register value with a structure:

```
struct exception_register
{
    bool enable_irq_0: 1;
    bool enable_irq_1: 1;
    bool enable_irq_2: 1;
    bool enable_irq_3: 1;
    bool irq_flag_0: 1;
    bool irq_flag_1: 1;
    bool irq_flag_2: 1;
    bool irq_flag_3: 1;
};

byte* the_register = 0x1234; // where 0x1234 is the address of the register in memory.
```

Then enabling exceptions 2 can be done like this:

```
the_register->enable_irq_2 = true;
```

Which is more readable than:

```
*the_register |= (1 << 2);
```

This is not intended to answer the question, but may help to understand why bitfields can be usefull.

Comment: The thing is, bitfields can be stored in any order. Accessing the third bitfield isn't the same as accessing the third bit. (It may be for your particular microcontroller compiler, but it doesn't _have_ to be.)

Comment: @Chris Lutz Didn't knew that. Yes, it may be compiler specific, or maybe there are some packing pragmas whichs tells the compiler not to reorder it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bitfield. [Example Bitfield](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node13.html#SECTION001321000000000000000)

Bitfield may be useful on small memory.