# Unions and bit fields — how do they work?

Tags: c, unions, bit-fields

I have some problems when trying to understand this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
    int entero;
    struct
    {
        unsigned short : 7;
        unsigned short valor: 1;
    } bin;
} conversor;

int main(void)
{
    int numero = 8, i;
    conversor conver;
    conver.entero = numero;

    for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d", conver.bin.valor );
        conver.entero <<= 1;
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

If someone would be so kind as to explain how this code converts an integer to binary as well, which makes each member of the union for example.

```
unsigned short : 7;
```

What is this for?

Comment: The only useful purpose I've seen `union` used for is to determine the worst alignment on the system for implementing an allocator.  For all other purposes, pretend `union` doesn't exist.

Comment: @Mooing Duck can you help me understand this code

Comment: Similarly, I'd recommend avoiding bitfields altogether. Compiler implementations tend to perform poorly, and are often buggy. If you need to pack multiple values into an integer, do it "manually" with bitwise operators.

Comment: I think you should print more information in the loop, and include a newline in the output. `for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) { printf( "%d: 0x%.4X %d\n", i, conver.entero, conver.bin.valor); conver.entero <<= 1; }`.  The output I got on Mac OS X 10.10.3 with GCC 4.9.1 was: `0: 0x0008 0` –
`1: 0x0010 0` –
`2: 0x0020 0` –
`3: 0x0040 0` –
`4: 0x0080 1` –
`5: 0x0100 0` –
`6: 0x0200 0` –
`7: 0x0400 0`.

Comment: @MooingDuck unions can also be used for aliasing (the strict aliasing rule does not apply to union-based aliasing). Although it is rare that aliasing is a genuine requirement.

Comment: The suggested duplicate [Simple C syntax Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370792/simple-c-syntax-question) asks "what is the bit-field syntax" given an example of it, rather than really delving into the nitty-gritty of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `int` is 4 bytes and `short` is 2, `conversor` will look something like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX // <- conversor union
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX // <- int entero
                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX // <- struct bin
                         XXXXXXX // <- anonymous field
                        X        // <- valor
                XXXXXXXX         // <- unused space from bin
```

A `union` will cram all its members in the same address and be as big as its largest member. A bit field will use bitwise operations to pack the field into individual bits, the width of which the user can explicitly specify.

Your code sets `entero` to 8, which will look like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000001000
```

Then `printf( "%d", conver.bin.valor );` will output the 8th bit, which is zero.

Then `conver.entero <<= 1;` will shift `entero` 1 bit to the left resulting in this:

```
00000000000000000000000000010000
```

This will multiply the value of the unnamed bit field by 2, valor will still be 0. Doing so 8 times will shift `entero` by 8 bits, and on `i == 3` `valor` will be "set" to 1 (since you output before you shift, the result will be output in the next iteration).

In that case, the unnamed bit field serves as 7 bits of padding, so that `valor` corresponds to the 8th bit of the `struct`.

Also note that the standard does not enforce a particular implementation for bit fields, but usually they follow common sense.

Comment: @Tony - what is unclear? It is unnamed, because access to it is not intended, its purpose is only to provide padding so that `valor` will be at the 8th bit.

Comment: I get it and valor because it is initialized to one

Comment: @Tony - this is not initialization. It specifies how many bits the field's width is. `valor` is 1 bit wide and can only hold values 0 or 1.

Comment: one last question because valor changes when i==3

Comment: When i is 3, 8 will be left shifted 4 times to result in 128, or in binary `10000000`, so the 8th bit where `valor` is will be 1. Another left shift will cause the 1 to go beyond `valor`'s location.

Comment: The number is 8 the one would be in the 4th bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75039/discussion-between-tony-and-ddriver).